# Cache Linq to Entities execution plan with Entity Framework 4

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, dbcontext

I'm profiling an ASP.NET web application and I'm noticing that my EF4 execution plans aren't being cached. Every time a page is loaded all Linq expressions are being recompiled, as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: dotTrace]

Is there any way I can tell EF4 to cache these execution plans?

EDIT:

This is what my queries look like:

```
var objs = db.Table
    .Include("OtherTable")
    .Where(g =>
        (someId != null || g.ID == someId) &&
        (g.ObjType == someType) &&
        (/* etc */))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Query Plan Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738562.aspx).  If your query's are created inefficiently they may not be cached.

Also each execution plan is cached per Application Domain.  So in ASP.Net this is the same as the AppPool and if you're AppPool shuts down or restarts the cache is cleared.

Comment: I'm not sure your link applies to my case. I'm not writing SQL by hand. I updated my question with some code.

Comment: Why don't you think the link applies?  It only talks about raw SQL in the context of dynamic queries.  The rest applies to Linq-to-Entities.

Comment: +1 for when cache is cleared, also there is the [cache eviction (part 3.2.2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853) which makes sure the cache only holds 800 entries